# How to not tell browser not to save cache

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a laravel 5.2 app. My problem comes every time I update my website, I have all my clients calling me because something is not working, and the problem is because some .js and .css are in the cache, and I have to explain them how to erase the cache.

What's the best solution?, How is the tag to tell the browsers to not cache my .js or .css (or some of them, specified)?.

Thank you

Comment: You could add a meta tag of no cache in the head of your page, also caching can be turned off on the hosting server i.e IIS

Comment: One solution would be to append a query string to your includes, like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css?2">` - notice the `?2`. This forces a refresh, but doesn't slow down load times by forcing it *every* time, only if the version is newer. Each time you make changes to the file, you can increase the number at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can version your JS and CSS when including them in your HTML by adding a version to the tag, such as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=3.4.1">`

When you make a change to the CSS or JS, change the version, and anyone visiting the page will load the new version instead of relying on the browser cache.

If you are using elixir with Laravel there are options included for versioning and cache-busting https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting

Answer (score 1):

The way of making the browser will not save cache is by creating a new version for the source each time any user get to the web page.

> The cache-buster query string can be updated so that the
>   browser doesn’t recognise the file in it’s cache and downloads a new
>   version.

I found a great information in the [cache boosting link](http://curtistimson.co.uk/front-end-dev/what-is-cache-busting/).

If you are using apache that [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) may be also very helpful.

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [answer] explains this under **Provide context for links**.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel there's a versioning for stylesheets and scripts. Use `laravel-elixir` can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting).

If version only css stylesheet then you can use like:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version('css/all.css');
});
```

and you will have something like this `all-16d570a7.css`

If you want multiple files like css and js:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version(['css/all.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

And finally to run this versions you can simply enter the command below in your console:
`gulp` or to be more specific `gulp version`.

Hope this could help.